# Share variable between HTML and AngularJS Directive with jQuery Flot

Tags: angularjs, charts, flot, directive

I have a variable in my template html (created from php side) and I need this variable in my angular directive (The aim it's to create a chart with jquery flot from values in php side).

My HTML :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var graphData = [{
             data : [[1375574400000, 20], [1375660800000, 30], [1375747200000, 35], [1375833600000, 39], [1375920000000, 45]],
             color: '#478e9c'
            }];
</script>
```

So, how I can use this variable in my angular directive ?
(I don't want to make an Ajax call in my directive)

Thanks !

Comment: The way you have it declared is as a global, so it can literally be accessed at `graphData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I come back with more experience.
The best solution it's to declare a service in the HTML and use it in directive.

HTML :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var graphData = [{
             data : [[1375574400000, 20], [1375660800000, 30], [1375747200000, 35], [1375833600000, 39], [1375920000000, 45]],
             color: '#478e9c'
            }];
    app.value("GraphDatas", graphData);
</script>
```

In JS:

```
app.directive("graph", ['GraphDatas', function(GraphDatas) {
   // do stuff with my tab GrapDatas
}]);
```

- Thanks to the very good book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028055.do
- Doc about services : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a connection between your controller and directive like this.

Controller:

```
$scope.graphData = $http({ ... make your request });
```

Directive:

```
// Add the scope attribute linked to your controller variable

.directive('thingy', function() {
    return {
        scope: { 
            graphData: "=graphData"
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

If that doesn't give you access to the scope variable, you may want to use '@' or '&' instead of '=' in the directive scope declaration. Another option is to get access from within the html element your directive uses. Like this:

```
<div thingy graphData="graphData"></div>
```

Comment: But I don't want use $http, I don't want make an other call to my PHP.
Maybe if I define my directive in my HTML ?

Comment: Where do you make the call to PHP the first time? Or where do you get the information from?

Comment: I use Symfony2, so my informations come to the controller. And I don't want define an other action just for return these datas (on call to the Mysql and I have already my informations when I display the HTML)

Comment: Perfect. You just need to get that information into a scope variable, and pass it into the directive like I showed. Sounds like it should be easy with what you have.

Comment: So, I just need to add $scope.graphData = my_data in the HTML, and define my directive in the JS file, right ?

Comment: Add $scope.graphData = my_data in your controller rather than the HTML, and yeah.

Comment: But it's my problem, I don't have these informations in my controller in my JS file, but just in my HTML file from php action